# Binary search tree traversal

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

Hi guys I have a doubt in inserting a new node in BST. In the **addNode** module I am trying to insert an element in the BST, but each time while adding a new node it is adding to the same root node which I passed from **main** function initially without traversing inside the tree.

This is the code which I have written.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
struct node* newNode(int data)
{
    node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    //struct temp = new node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return(temp);
};
int addNode(node *dest, node *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"adding data to node for "<< dest->data<<endl;
        root = dest;
        cout<<"ROOT VALUE = root->data "<<root->data<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if(dest->data > root->data)
    {
        cout<<"Traverse right for "<<dest->data<<endl;
        addNode(dest, root->right);
    }
    else if(dest->data < root->data)
    {
        cout<<"Traverse left for "<<dest->data<<endl;
        addNode(dest, root->left);
    }
}
void printNodes(node *root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        printNodes(root->left);
        if(root->left != NULL && root->right != NULL)
            std::cout<< root->data <<" ";
        printNodes(root->right);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i, j, k, flag;
    int arr[6] = {4, 2,8, 1, 0, 10};
    node *start = newNode(arr[0]);
    for(i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        node *newOne = newNode(0);
        newOne->data = arr[i];
        cout<<"NODE DATA - start->data "<<start->data;
        if(addNode(newOne, start))
            std::cout<<"\nNode added"<<endl;
    }
    printNodes(start);
    return 1;
}
```

I am quite new to trees concept as well as pointers concept in trees. Any help is appreciated and thank you.

Comment: There's nothing special about pointers. Assigning to a pointer parameter is no different from assigning to an `int` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... but each time while adding a new node it is adding to the same root
>   node

This is because you are adding it always to the same root, as here

```
if(addNode(newOne, start))
```

`start` is always the same. You could make `addNode` return the new root and call it like that:

```
start = addNode(newOne,start);
```

I'll leave it to you to implement it.

Note that parameters are always passed by value in c++ (unless you pass-by-reference), thus changing the parameter inside the method, `root = dest;`, has no effect on the `start` in `main`.